# Marketing Cloud Mobile Studio Subscriber key

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilesdk, mobilepush, mobilepush-android, mobilepush-ios

I'm trying to understand how I can do targetted push notifications from Marketing Cloud within a journey.

I'm having a hard time understanding how will I identify specific people and setting their subscriber key in Mobile Studio.

They will have to login using their email address and password in the app, so I will know their email address, but not their EmailStudio subscriber key.

I know that there is the `setSubscriberKey` command in the SKD, but I wonder if i have to retrieve the `subscriberkey` from email studio based on the email address and then used that to setSubscriberKey in MobilePush.

I suppose the `subsciberkey` should be the same in EmailStudio and MobilePush to be able to send emails/push notifications to a person in the same journey.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct; `Subscriber Key` is the 1 value that allows you to reconcile contacts between Email Studio and Mobile Push.  How/where you get/store that data is up to you, but you will need to call the SDKs' convenience methods to assign the value for the consumer's device.

Comment: Thank you! So this is a viable solutions: I do an API call into emailstudio from the app, to get the subscriber key based on email address and set that as the SubscriberKey in MobilePush?

Comment: Yes, that should associate the contacts.